# What happens if a high priority thread is waiting for a "Thread Flag" and a low priority thread sets that Thread flag

Tags: multithreading, embedded, rtos

Apologies, if it is not the right place for this question.
I am working on an RTOS (RTX), my question is if a High Priority Thread is waiting for a Thread Flag (says the flag is X_High) (currently is in a blocked state) and a Low Priority Thread is running, and this low priority thread sets "X_High" thread flag.
Would context switching from low priority to High Thread take place immediately or low priority thread will keep on running till a blocking statement (Delay or waiting for thread flag)?

Answer (score 3):

The guarantee of a pre-emptive priority bases real-time scheduler is that the highest priority thread that is ready to run, will run (outside if interrupt processing).

The scheduling decision is made whenever a scheduling call is made in a normal thread and in exit from the interrupt context.  `osEventFlagsSet` is a scheduling call. If any event set by it causes a higher priority thread to become ready, the calling thread is pre-empted immediately (before the function returns).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand that "osEventFlagSet" and "osThreadFlagSet" can cause context switching. Is it true in the case of Mutex and Semaphore?

Comment: @Harjeev.Sharma. They are all "scheduling objects" semaphore give and mutex release cause scheduling, as do delay, yield, and message send.  In general any call that can cause a task to block.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific RTOS you're using, and how it is configured. For example, *FreeRTOS* can be configured to use either cooperative scheduling or preemptive scheduling. When using preemptive scheduling, task switching takes place as soon as the flag is set (semaphore is given). But when using cooperative scheduling, task switching takes place when the currently running task is blocked, or yields voluntarily.

Comment: He says which RTOS he is using!

Comment: Although I would argue that if you used cooperative scheduling, it is no longer a real-time operating system.  So it does not really "depend".  That is not to say a cooperatively scheduled system cannot be real-time, but rather that the RTOS guarantees if determinism do not apply.  Apart from that RTX does not have that option.

Comment: @TomV , Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Re, "It depends on the specific RTOS you're using..." I would be surprised if there was any RTOS in which an OS call that was intended for communication between threads was _not_ a yield point.

Comment: @SolomonSlow , AFAIK, in cooperative mode FreeRTOS tasks don't yield automatically unless they are blocked.

Comment: I can't find anything in FreeRTOS docs that explicitly says which OS calls are yield points and which are not, but for example, in the [documentation for `xEventGroupSetBits`](https://www.freertos.org/xEventGroupSetBits.html), it says, "Setting bits in an event group will automatically unblock tasks that are blocked waiting for the bits." I'm inclined to assume that "_automatically_ unblock" means the same as "yield." I.E., if some high priority task A is unblocked by lower-priority task B calling `xEventGroupSetBits`, then task A will get to run _before_ the call returns in task B.